# How to split a list of numbers into a set of list with all the numbers in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, recursion

How do i split a list in Haskell, for example, "222 33244" into ["222","33","2","444"] only through recursion and fuctions on the prelude?

My current attempt is:

```
list xs
  |length xs == 0 = ""
  |otherwise = listSplit xs

 listSplit (x:xs)
  |x == head xs = x : ListSplitNext x xs
  |otherwise = x:[]

 listSplitNext a (x:xs)
  |a == x = a : listSplitNext x xs
  |otherwise = listSplit xs
```

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: I haven't tried yet i would like to know how to code the problem

Comment: Basically u receive a list and then u gotta split it like that and i don't know how to do it

Comment: Homework questions without an attempt are off-topic on StackOverflow: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems/

Comment: I've tried to do it but my code doesn't work. I tried to code it like first u check if the first element of the list is equal to the next one if it is u keep checking if it isnt u split it

Comment: But the way i did it doesn't work

Comment: i've been trying to do this for a week now so that's why i'm asking for help

Comment: well you can share the attempt that does not work, such that we can help fixing it.

Comment: List xs = ListSplit xs
ListSplit (x:xs)
      |x == head xs = x : ListSplit x xs
      |otherwise = x:[]

Comment: Ok, a first problem I spot is that your function starts with an *uppercase*. Functions start with a lowercase in Haskell. It is also not clear to me why you define two functions: `List` and `SplitList`, since you basically define `List` to be exactly the same as `SplitList`.

Comment: i know but the first function has more than 1 guard

Comment: list xs
      |length xs == 0 = ""
      |otherwise = listSplit xs
      
listSplit (x:xs)
      |x == head xs = x : ListSplit x xs
      |otherwise = x:[]

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: Try `words`, it is in the Prelude.

Comment: Please see [ask] and at the very least explain __why__ it doesn't work. For bonus points, also explain the reasoning behind your current approach. Help us help you!

Comment: You might also want to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You could get the `head` then `takeWhile` elements are equal. Then `dropWhile` those values. Recurse until `[]`. Maybe `filter` everything but numbers out first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since I don't quite understand your approach and ghci lists 18 compile errors in your code, I'm afraid I can't help you with your attempt at a solution.

As pointed out in a comment, a possible solution would be:

```
listSplit xs = listSplit' [] (filter (`elem` ['0'..'9']) xs)

listSplit' ws (x:xs) = listSplit' (ws ++ [x : takeWhile (==x) xs]) (dropWhile (==x) xs)
listSplit' ws [] = ws
```

1. Filter every element of the string that is not a number (Data.Char.isNumber would do this, too, but the premise was to only use Prelude functions) and call `listSplit'` on the filtered list.
2. `(ws ++ [x : takeWhile (==x) xs])` collects everything in `xs` until it reaches a letter that does not equal `x`, wraps this in a list and appends it to `ws`.
3. `(dropWhile (==x) xs)` removes every letter in `xs` until it reaches a letter that does not equal `x`.
4. Finally, the function calls itself with the updated `ws` and the reduced `xs`
5. If there are no more remaining elements, the function returns `ws`

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use very few pre-defined functions this might give you some ideas:

```
listSplit :: String -> [String]
listSplit xs =
  let (as, a) = foldr go ([], []) numbers
  in  a : as
 where
  isNumber x = x `elem` ['0'..'9']
  numbers    = filter isNumber xs

  go cur (res, []) = (res, [cur])
  go cur (res, lst@(a:_))
    | a == cur  = (res, a : lst)
    | otherwise = (lst : res, [cur])
```

Of course you can replace `foldr` with your own recursion as well:

```
numberSplit :: String -> [String]
numberSplit xs =
  let numbers = filter (`elem` ['0'..'9']) xs
  in  listSplit numbers


listSplit :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
listSplit =
  reverse . go [] []
 where
  go acc as [] = as : acc
  go acc [] (x:xs) = go acc [x] xs
  go acc as@(a:_) (x:xs)
    | a == x    = go acc (a : as) xs
    | otherwise = go (as : acc) [x] xs
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a moment to implement this but I think this is what you're looking for.

```
listSplit s = go filtered
  where filtered = [c | c <- s, elem c ['0'..'9']]
        go [] = []
        go (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (== x) xs) : (go $ dropWhile (== x) xs)
```